# AppleScript, check if folder exist in current users home directory

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to create a script that checks if a folder exist on the currents users desktop,

```
tell application "Finder"

    set RAIDFolder to POSIX path of (path to desktop) & "RAID"
    if exists folder RAIDFolder then
        display notification "" with title "RAID" subtitle "FOUND IT " & RAIDFolder
    else
        display notification "" with title "RAID" subtitle "NOT FOUND " & RAIDFolder
    end if
end tell
```

But I cannot get it to work, it always goes to display notification:

"NOT FOUND /Users/edit02/Desktop/RAID

Which is the correct path its looking for. I'm fairly fresh in applescripts, and scripting in general, som any help to why I can't get it to display that it detected the folder is appreciated.

This is for a script for several editing stations which all have different usernames, and I want it to check for a folder on desktop, and if missing sync folder from a local raid.

Also, would a symlink folder show as a folder to a `if exist folder`command?
I have tested both.

Thanks John I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not thinking like AppleScript — in particular, you are not thinking like the scriptable Finder. It doesn't think in posix paths. If you're going to convert to a posix path, you've basically stepped outside the Finder's world of thought — and then you can't come back to it and expect it to understand the posix path.

---

If you just want to know whether there is a folder called `"RAID"` on the desktop using the Finder and AppleScript, simply say

```
tell application "Finder"
    exists folder "RAID" of desktop
end tell
```

That results in `true` if there is such a folder and `false` otherwise.

---

If you insist on talking about posix paths, then don't talk to the Finder. Just say, totally outside of any app `tell` block:

```
set deskpath to get POSIX path of (get path to desktop)
set raidfile to POSIX file (deskpath & "RAID")
```

*Now* if you want to know whether that exists as a folder, you can ask the Finder. But when you do, it will throw an error if it doesn't, so you have to catch that error:

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        exists folder raidfile
    on error
        false
    end try
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I know how to use basic if, then else commands, but how can I use this true/fase statement to perform an specific action for true or false. E.g. I want to run create the missing folder if false and only display a notification if found?

Comment: Just say `if result` after that code, and carry on from there.

Comment: Thanks again! Lifesaver! And even found out if I change POSIX path to file, it detects my symlinks as well.

Comment: Thanks for checking that part!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd *code* it:

```applescript
set RAIDFolder to POSIX path of (path to desktop) & "RAID"

tell application "System Events" to set theFolderExists to exists folder RAIDFolder

if theFolderExists then
    display notification "" with title "RAID" subtitle "FOUND IT " & RAIDFolder
else
    display notification "" with title "RAID" subtitle "NOT FOUND " & RAIDFolder
end if
```